# Auto enumerar cada año un campo

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero que el campo anualNo se enumere cada año.
y me gustaria esta misma consulta pasarla a laravel eloquent.

```
INSERT INTO registro (Id, anualNo, año)
VALUES ('1', 1, 2019),
VALUES ('2', 2, 2019),
VALUES ('3', 3, 2019),
VALUES ('4', 4, 2019),
VALUES ('5', 1, 2020),
VALUES ('6', 2, 2020),
VALUES ('7', 3, 2020);
```

no se si mi ejemplo está bien

```
INSERT INTO `registro`(`Id`, `anualNo`, `año`) 
VALUES (
    '20',
    (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(año),0)+1 FROM registro WHERE YEAR(año)=2020),
    '2020-02-03'
);
```

mi error

```
1093 - You can't specify target table 'registro' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: Entonces la pregunta primero debe ir en razón de hacer funcionar la consulta SQL y posterior ya considerar lo de Eloquent

Comment: Ya tienes creado tu Model? Y lo que te dice beta es crucial, sino funciona el SQL puro que vas a pasar a eloquent, primero has funcionar tu SQL.

Comment: ya lo probe y el error que me da es este: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'registro' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Que versión de mysql usas?

Comment: No veo para que almacenar esa numeración, sería mucho más simple con una window function como row_number al hacer un Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En eloquent puedes hacerlo así :

```
Registro::select('anualNo')->orderBy('anualNo', 'desc')->where('año', 2019)->first()
```

Ordenando de manera descendente obtienes  el último registro del año 2019, lo guardas en una variable, y aplicas $ultimo_id +1

Recuerda tener cuidado con los caracteres especiales en los nombres de las columnas como **año**

Comment: Se podrá hacer en una sola consulta cuando se hace el insert?